# Access violation writing location - 2D character array

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a snake clone in the windows console.
I'm trying to draw the borders using this function:

```
void drawBorder(uint16_t width, uint16_t height)
{
    char **a=NULL;

 a = malloc(sizeof(char) * height);
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < height; i++)
        a[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * width);

    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (uint16_t j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0 || j == width - 1 || i == height - 1 || i == 0)
                a[i][j] = '#';
            else
                a[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }

    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (uint16_t j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

If a pass a height greater than 32 I get the "Access violation writing location" error. If it's less or equal to 32 it seems to be working fine.

Comment: `a = malloc(sizeof(char) * height);` should be `a = malloc(sizeof(char*) * height);`

Comment: A common way to avoid this sort of type error is to use the variable you're assigning to in the `sizeof` expression, in your case `a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * height);`.